# Install NodeJS packages from file with NPM install

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, node.js, package

Is it possible to install [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) packages (/modules) from files like in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)'s Gemfile as done with `bundle install` or [python](/questions/tagged/python)'s requirements file (eg: `requirements.pip`) as done using `pip install -r` commands ?

Say I have a file where three or four package names are listed.

How would I instruct `npm` to install packages whose names are found in that file (and resolve dependencies which it also does)?

Comment: I don't really understand the question but you can check the documentation for npm install and that might help https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: I already checked the documentation. Basically I'm asking for a direct `bundle install` and `pip install -r` alternatives if you are familiar with those languages.

Comment: So are you asking if you can use npm to read a gemfile or a python requirements file? Or are you asking if there's some equivalent to those for node?

Comment: As some answers already mention the equivalent of ruby's gemfile and python's requirement's file in is the [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file. Every package on npm has one and the dependencies you need are listed in a field called "dependencies" which you can manually update or update by using `npm install <package> --save`

Comment: I am asking if it is possible to have just one `package.json` file to keep all the packages I need inside of it and then install all of them with a single `npm install` command.

Answer (score 1):

Just create your package JSON, you can use yarn to manage your packages instead of npm, it's faster.

Inside your package you can create a section of scripts accessed by `npm run`

`scripts: {
  customBuild: 'your sh code/ruby/script whateve'
}`

And after you can run on terminal, `npm run customBuild` for example

Answer (score 0):

you can use NPM init to create a package.json file which will store the node packages your application is dependent on, then use npm install which will install the node packages indicated in the package.json file